# NoMethodError users_url with devise (ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise 2.2.2 with rails 3.2.11

I use devise with ajax requests

I changed the following configuration in `initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.navigational_formats = [:json, :html]
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

when I submit an empty sign in request, I expect to get a json response with errors hash, but i get a 500 instead (see below for the trace) (it works fine with sign up request)

here are my routes (nothing special)

```
devise_for :users
```

the trace:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-27 13:33:45 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fe88ddd9550>):
```

Comment: I had this problem a few days ago and then magically disappeared.

Comment: it helps a lot ;o), is your app available on github?

Comment: No, unfortunately is private.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overriding `after_sign_in_path_for` and have a code path in there that returns nil.

This causes devise to fall back to its default behaviour and call `users_url` to get the path to redirect to.

Why do I think this? Because you are having the same error I had (and lost some hair over) and also [this bug report](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1350#issuecomment-50862868) contains the github usernames of many other people who have been humbled by this particular issue.